# Suppose that $\lim_{n→∞} \frac{S_n}{n} > 0$ Show that $S_n → ∞$. ($S_n$ is a sequence)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

So at first glance it appeared pretty easy, we can assume by contradiction that sn converges to some constant L, then $\lim(\frac{S_n}{n})$ as n approaches infinity is $\lim(\frac{L}{n})$ which is zero hence a contradiction (0>0 wrong statement). but after thinking about it $\lim(\frac{L}{n})$ approaches zero but never exactly zero,so the statement $\lim(\frac{L}{n})>0$ is not wrong. am i overthinking this?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/. In any case, if $L=\lim S_n/n>0$, then eventually $S_n/n>L/2$.

Comment: You clearly cannot just take limits of some parts and leave other parts unaltered.

Comment: Also by contradictory, the limit $\lim S_n$ does not necessarily exists.

Comment: i used the property: lim(Sn/n)=limSn/limn=L/infinity= 0

Comment: The statement in your final sentence *is* wrong. lim(L/n) = 0, it's not >0. Just because the members of the *sequence* "is never exactly zero", this doesn't mean the *limit* cannot equal zero (which is does).

Answer (score 1):

Yes we could prove by contradiction considering all the cases:

- $S_n\to l \implies \frac{S_n}n \to 0$
- $S_n\to -\infty \implies \frac{S_n}n \to m$ with $m\le 0$ (to prove better with detail)
- limit doesn't exists (we need to consider $\limsup$ and $\liminf$)

As a simpler alternative, by definition we have that

$$S_n/n \to L>0 \implies \forall \epsilon \quad\exists n_0\quad \forall n>n_0\quad |S_n/n-L|<\epsilon$$

that is, assuming $\epsilon=L/2$, $\forall n>n_0$ we have

$$S_n/n> L/2 \implies S_n>n\cdot L/2$$

Comment: how did you get ϵ?

Comment: @Megan The definition of limit implies that we approach $L$ as much as we wont, then it suffices to find $n_0$ such that $L/2<S_n/n<3L/2$ and form here we can conclude by squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Let $0<L=\lim_{n\to \infty}S_n/n.$ For any $e>0$ there exists $n_e\in \Bbb N$ such that $n\ge n_e\implies |S_n/n-L|<e.$ In particular, with $e=L/2$ we have $$n\ge n_{L/2}\implies |S_n/n-L|<L/2\implies$$ $$\implies S_n/n-L\ge -L/2\implies$$ $$\implies S_n/n>L/2\implies$$ $$\implies S_n>n(L/2).$$

Now, given any $x\in \Bbb R,$ take $m_x\in \Bbb N$ such that $m_x(L/2)>x.$ And let $p_x=\max (n_{L/2},m_x).$ Then  $$n\ge p_x \implies S_n>n(L/2) \quad \text {(because $n\ge n_{L/2}$)}$$ $$ \ge m_x(L/2)\quad \text {(because $n\ge m_x$)}$$ $$>x.$$

Answer (score 0):

The statement in your final sentence is wrong. lim(L/n) = 0, it's not >0. Just because the members of the sequence are "never exactly zero", this doesn't mean the limit cannot equal zero (which is does).